# CPAN install almost never works on the Mac, is this normal?

Tags: macos, perl, module, cpan

I'm new to using Perl on my Mac at home (Lion).  I installed xcode and developer tools which gets me /opt/local/bin/cpan.  GREAT.

So, I enabled dependencies with "o conf" to install dependencies as needed, otherwise it seems almost useless without it.

Every module I try to install fails. I get reams and reams of output etc etc.. But at the end of what seems to be endless pages of tests and other dependencies trying to be installed, it almost always fails unless it is a very simple basic module.

So, is this normal for the Mac OS platform?  Should I just look at MacPorts for everything?

Or maybe my system is configured wrong?

I run cpan as sudo.  I was setting makepl_arg and setting a PREFIX to my ~user directory. I figured if this is gonna all blow up, why risk installing or partially installing crap into my root perl filesystem (though perhaps cpan is smart and does this off in a workspace)

Thanks

Comment: I'm reading "It's broken! Is it normal for it to be broken?" Which is either the weirdest question, or a plea for help that's completely absent of any actual information. (Well, I guess we know what platform you're using.) If it is a plea for help, tell us exactly what you did and what you get.

Comment: You installed XCode *and* Developer Tools? Aren't they the same thing nowadays? Also, you can't install any modules, or you can install some modules? I suggest you pick a module you want to use and start with that. Give details of what goes wrong.

Comment: You say etc., but the reams of output have the clues you need to figure out what the problem was. But only you have those clues because your question didn't include a single line of the output. How did this question get any upvotes?

Comment: Show us some of the output that you get, and show us your cpan configuration. It's certainly not normal for it to fail on OS X since that's where I use it the most. :)

Comment: Xcode and developer tools do not create anything in /opt so what exactly have you installed?

Answer (score 2):

I've got no problem with Perl on OSX. I simply installed [Perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/) and cpanp, because I didn't want to mess with the Perl distribution that comes bundled with Mac OS X...